# Fix incomplete character string for year "2016" from "0016" in R

Tags: r, date, datetime, format, character

I've tried to find another question like this one but there doesn't seem to be one out there... My question is simple:

I have a data frame that looked like this but I want the format to read YYYY-MM-DD:

```
> df$Date
      Date    
1   10/23/16        
2   10/24/16         
3   10/25/16
```

So I coded it up but it returned me this:

```
df$Date <- strptime(as.character(df$Date), "%m/%d/%Y")
df$Date <- format(df$Date, "%Y-%m-%d")

> df$Date
      Date    
1   0016-10-23       
2   0016-10-24         
3   0016-10-25
```

Any ideas for how I can make the year 2016 instead of 0016?

Thanks!

Comment: Dont you just need `as.Date('10/23/16', format = '%m/%d/%y')` ? Replace `Y` with `y`

Comment: Or use lubridate() mdy().

Comment: Try this: `format(as.Date(df$Date, '%m/%d/%y'), '%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: I want it to be a full "2016" so that I can compare the values with another data frame in that format.

Comment: I have added solution for you. Kindly check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly go through following R console code snippet:

```
> dates <- c("10/23/16", "10/24/16")
> dates
[1] "10/23/16" "10/24/16"
> Dates <- as.Date(dates,
        +   format = "%m/%d/%y")
> Dates
[1] "2016-10-23" "2016-10-24"
```

Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
format(as.Date(df$Date, '%m/%d/%y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
#[1] "2016-10-23" "2016-10-24" "2016-10-25"
format(as.Date(df$Date, '%m/%d/%y'), '%Y-%b-%d')
#[1] "2016-Oct-23" "2016-Oct-24" "2016-Oct-25"
```

Comment: Why is it wrapped in `format` ? What is the output of `as.Date(df$Date, '%m/%d/%y')` ?

Comment: I don't see the point of the format here.

Comment: @RonakShah you are right, only `as.Date(df$Date, '%m/%d/%y')` works since `%Y-%m-%d` is the default for `Date`,the outer `format` is just to make it more generic, just to ensure it works even if OP wants any other format on top.